# Send Message from Aweber API

Tags: php, aweber

How can we send message to all my subscribers in aweber list. https://labs.aweber.com/snippets/authentication but didn't find anything relevant to send message to subscribers.

Is there any option from API to send messages or broadcast a message through API ??

Answer (score 2):

No can do unfortunately.

You can create a new campaign by POSTing the the API url given, they offer no way to send the campaign. See [reference docs](https://labs.aweber.com/docs/reference/1.0#campaign_collection)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest downloading the php library thats available on github:

https://github.com/aweber/AWeber-API-PHP-Library